# what is the meaning of UUID error description = not found

Tags: windows, uuid

My app failed to fetch a UUID on one of our customer machines. I ran below command on this machine I got the below error

```
wmic path win32_computersystemproduct get uuid
ERROR
Description = Not Found
```

Could someone explain to me the meaning of this error? Does it mean UUID is not found or an error description is unavailable?

What could be a possible reason for this error? I have no idea how to proceed with this error. The customer did mention the app had been working until recently.

google doesn't help me much on this.

Comment: MSDN says this comes from SMBIOS so I suppose not all systems have it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this with one of my clients just today and found it was linked to a Webm (RSOP) issue. I had to rebuild the user's directory using a copy of a working C:\Windows\System32\webm

1. Disable and stop the Windows Management Instrumentation service.
2. Delete contents of "C:\windows\system32\wbem\Repository" folder after taking a backup.
3. Get the files under the wbem folder from a similar working machine excluding the files.
4. Enable and start the Windows Management Instrumentation service again
5. Run the command

> for /f %s in ('dir /b *.mof *.mfl') do mofcomp %s

to recompile the mof's so that they data can be parsed into the repository.

Reboot and try to run gpupdate /force again and *if* it succeeds, you should be able to pull the UUID after that.

Godspeed.
Jared Barr